# different filters for UITextField's (instance variables)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use instance variables of UITextField and set different filter for each UITextField instance. How can I do it?

```
class ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

...

func ... {
   ...
   textField1.delegate = self
   textField2.delegate = self
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // but the problem that textField1, textField2 should be class variables, not instance variables...

    if textField1 == textField {

        let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
        let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
        let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
        return string == numberFiltered
    } else if textField2 == textField { ... }

...

}
```

**update**

In Android I can do something like this

```
editText1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    // if...
    return ...
   };
 });

editText2.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    // if...
    return ...
   };
 });
```

both `editText1` and `editText2` are instance variables

Comment: I wonder what is the problem

Comment: Please further explain the problem, and explain the code you have shared.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't want `textField1`, `textField2` to be class variables but instance variables

Comment: @Sh_Khan updated the question, example with Android

Comment: @NiallKiddle updated the question, example with Android

Comment: In the code you say "should be class variables" and in your comment you say you don't want them to be class variables but instance variables. Which is it? What you're doing in the code is pretty much all you need already...

Comment: @Manuel `but the problem that textField1, textField2 should be class variables` you didn't understand, here I mean that for the current solution they should be class variables (won't work with instance variables), but I don't want to use such solution.. I want to find a solution to use instance variables

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that indicates they are class variables. `textField1` and `textField2` could have been declared as instance variables (the common thing in a view controller would have been outlets loaded from a storyboard: `@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextfield?` ) and the code you posted would work just as well, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar by creating separate UITextFieldDelegate sub-classes, and assigning those as the delegates.

Basic approach:

```
class AlphaOnlyTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("Alpha:", string)
        // do what you want - such as allowing only Alpha chars
        return true
    }

}

class NumbersOnlyTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("Numbers:", string)
        // do what you want - such as allowing only Numeric chars
        return true
    }

}

class TheChildVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tfAlpha: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var tfNumbers: UITextField!

    var alphaDelegate = AlphaOnlyTextFieldDelegate()
    var numbersDelegate = NumbersOnlyTextFieldDelegate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tfAlpha.delegate = alphaDelegate
        tfNumbers.delegate = numbersDelegate

    }

}
```

**Edit:**

One advantage to the above is that you can assign the "pre-designed" delegate to any text field.

Another approach would be to sub-class `UITextField`, with its delegate functions as part of itself:

```
class AlphaTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("Alpha Class:", string)
        // do what you want - such as allowing only Alpha chars
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah thanks. it's bad `Swift`, `C#` don't have anonymous class like in `Java`, code would look simpler, not that much lines, not scattered, code would be placed next to other editText methods (to set other properties)

Comment: Each has its own drawbacks and benefits... another approach would be to sub-class `UITextField` - see the edit to my answer.